# trigger to duplicate rows in same table in mysql for class timetable

Tags: mysql, triggers, duplicates, rows

I'm making a class timetable. There are 5 classes, each class occurs once every week. I have two tables a class table and a schedule table.

I'm trying to make a trigger where the row will be duplicated on the same table, but entered on a different date. I also need that row to be deleted after insert.

I have this so far:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `erase`// 
CREATE TRIGGER `erase` BEFORE DELETE ON `flsch`
FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO flsch SELECT * FROM flsch WHERE DATE_ID=old.DATE_ID
```

Is there any way this can be done?

@Devart I've added the new piece of code as requested below:

```
DELIMITER $$

 CREATE PROCEDURE add_f(IN param_DATEID TIMESTAMP, IN param_SNO VARCHAR(6), IN param_sub VARCHAR(20), IN param_SCHD INT(4))


BEGIN
IF SNO ='math01'
INSERT INTO schtt VALUES(param_DATEID, param_SNO, param_SUB, param_SCHD);
INSERT INTO schtt VALUES(param_DATEID + INTERVAL 7 DAY, param_SNO, param_SUB, param_SCHD);
END IF;

ELSE IF SNO='eng101'

INSERT INTO schtt VALUES(param_DATEID, param_SNO, param_SUB, param_SCHD);
INSERT INTO schtt VALUES((param_DATEID + INTERVAL 1 DAY) + INTERVAL 7 DAY, param_SNO, param_SUB, param_SCHD);
END IF;
END 

$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Can I enter a string which will delete a record after a certain date with a PROCEDURE, or can that only be done through a Trigger

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done with a help of trigger because of restriction - *Within a stored function or trigger, it is not permitted to modify a table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the function or trigger.*

Write a stored procedure to perform logic or do it in the application.

---

OK, suppose that we have a table, and we need to add a record and duplicated record with different date, the stored procedure can help us:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  name VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  dt DATE DEFAULT NULL
);

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE add_two_records(IN param_name VARCHAR(255), IN param_dt DATE)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(param_name, param_dt);
  INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(param_name, param_dt + INTERVAL 1 DAY);
END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Add records:

```
CALL add_two_records('Rick', '2012-01-16');
```

Let's check result:

```
SELECT * FROM table1;
+------+------------+
| name | dt         |
+------+------------+
| Rick | 2012-01-16 |
| Rick | 2012-01-17 |
+------+------------+
```

---

Syntax error fixes:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE add_f(IN param_DATEID TIMESTAMP, IN param_SNO VARCHAR(6), IN param_sub VARCHAR(20), IN param_SCHD INT(4))
BEGIN
IF param_SNO ='math01' THEN
  INSERT INTO schtt VALUES(param_DATEID, param_SNO, param_SUB, param_SCHD);
  INSERT INTO schtt VALUES(param_DATEID + INTERVAL 7 DAY, param_SNO, param_SUB, param_SCHD);
ELSE IF param_SNO='eng101' THEN
  INSERT INTO schtt VALUES(param_DATEID, param_SNO, param_SUB, param_SCHD);
  INSERT INTO schtt VALUES((param_DATEID + INTERVAL 1 DAY) + INTERVAL 7 DAY, param_SNO, param_SUB, param_SCHD);

  -- You can use this one -
  -- INSERT INTO schtt VALUES(param_DATEID + INTERVAL 8 DAY, param_SNO, param_SUB, param_SCHD);
END IF;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

You asked:

> Can I enter a string which will delete a record after a certain date with a PROCEDURE...

Yes, you can do it with a DELETE statement + WHERE clause.

Comment: I'm kind of new to MySQL. Would you be able to explain that with more depth.. thanks :)

Comment: thanks @Devart it was really helpful and thanks for the explanation.
I'm just having a little bit of trouble with setting the subject_ID. 
I want the procedure to insert the records into the the schedule table where the subject_id ='math01'.. but its gibing me a syntax error when i do this 'code'   INSERT INTO schtt VALUES WHERE subject_id = 'BG0002'(DATE_ID + INTERVAL 1 DAY, subject_id, teacher, sched_TIME); 'code' 

also if i do 'code' select * from schtt 'code in the procedure will i be able to read the current table information and copy into the new record.

Comment: If you want to insert a record from the same table, then you can use INSERT...SELECT statement, e.g. INSERT INTO schtt SELECT subject_id, date + INTERVAL 1 DAY FROM schtt WHERE subject_id = 1; Statement syntax - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select-into-statement.html

Comment: i'm having some difficulty entering the current date into the date_id timestamp field. I've tried using SET, and functions such as NOW() to define the DATE_ID as the default value. But they havent worked.

The timestamp appears as 0000-00-00 0000. I'm trying to get it to show the current time and then to add the next row 7 days according to current time. Would anyone be able to tell me where Im going wrong? Thanks :)

Comment: It should work with TIMESTAMP date type. Maybe something is wrong, try to find an error. Or provide information to show the problem (CREATE TABLE, CREATE PROCEDURE, ...)

Comment: 'code' 
CREATE PROCEDURE add_two_records(IN DATE_ID TIMESTAMP, IN SUBJECT_ID VARCHAR(6), IN SUB_NAME VARCHAR(20), IN SCHED_TIME INT(4))
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO schtt SELECT DATE_ID + INTERVAL 7 DAY, SUBJECT_ID, SUB_NAME, SCHED_TIME FROM schtt WHERE SUBJECT_ID = 'BG0002';
 
END
$$

DELIMITER ; 'CODE'

I'm using this CALL method to add the two records:
CALL add_two_records('DATE_ID', 'SUBJECT_ID', 'SUB_NAME', 'SCHED_TIME');

I also tried DECLARE after beginning for the timestamp field. However, it did not work. :(

Comment: Check if procedure parameters and table fields have the same names. The have to be different.

Comment: Thanks @Devart. A bit embarrassing but, the parameters were not different from the table :/ thanks for pointing that out. I have managed to succesfully insert a class into the schedule table and one 7 days later at the same time. 

I can insert maths subject into the table to show its happening today(e.g 1/Jan, and 7 days(7/Jan) later.. I am trying to add another subject that happens tommorrow (2/Jan) and show it reoccurs 7 days later on 9 Jan.. I've tried 'code' ((subject_id, date + INTERVAL 1 DAY) + INTERVAL 7 day  .. but that gives me a syntax error :/

Comment: SOLVED :) I changed the ELSE IF to END IF; ,started a NEW IF and ended with another END IF; It works. Im just going to work on the DELETE statement now. PS thanks for again for the assistance @Devart